# How can I spell out numbers in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

There have been many times when I've wanted the cardinal version instead of the numeral version of a number. You could use a lookup table where you've typed out all the possible names but it's a pain to fill the whole thing in and then the formula only works for the number's you've manually typed.

How can I take any numeric value in Excel and spell it out in English?

Comment: FYI, when you plan a self-answered question, there is a checkbox during question creation to select "answer the question yourself".  That defers posting the question until your answer is ready.  It saves helpful people posting clarifying questions in comments before your answer shows up.

Comment: @fixer1234 Thanks. I tried to do that. It errored due to the character length but still posted the question. Apologies for any confusion. Never before have I tried to use more than 30,000 characters in a post.

Comment: Is this a common problem? I have never run into this..

Answer (score 2):

### Answer Part 1 of 3

**This answer is being posted in three parts due to the character limit**

**EDIT:** Based on Patrick's reworking of my original answer, I have reviewed my own code and made some improvement. Specifically, I tightened up the handling for decimal values.

Well, totally random OP of whom I know nothing, you're in luck! I had an eerily similar need and wrote the VBA function to do it. As it is, it can handle any number up to 10^{+/- 3,012} but that can be expanded or reduced as desired.

It's important the the number is passed in as a *string*. That's the only way that Excel can handle numbers that large without converting it to scientific notation.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function SpellNumber(ByVal arabicNumberString As String, Optional conversionCase As VbStrConv = vbProperCase) As String
    'Spells out a number in English (uses the Short Scale names)
    'If you try to use a very large number, you must convert it to a string before sending it
    'Otherwise, Excel may convert it to scientific notation before passing it to the VBA
    'You can do this with the TEXT formula such as TEXT(A1,"0")
    
    'Orders of Magnitude: (negative powers of ten can be inferred by symmetry and adding "th(s)")
    'Words                  Power   Decimal
    '------------------------------------------
    'One                    10^0    1   (not used when writing numbers as words)
    'Ten                    10^1    10  (not used when writing numbers as words)
    'Hundred                10^2    100
    'Thousand               10^3    1,000
    'Million                10^6    1,000,000
    'Billion                10^9    1,000,000,000
    'Trillion               10^12   1,000,000,000,000
    'Quadrillion            10^15   1,000,000,000,000,000
    'Quintillion            10^18   1,000,000,000,000,000,000
    'Sextillion             10^21   1,000,000,000,000,000,000,000
    'Septillion             10^24   1,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000
    'Octillion              10^27   1,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000
    'Nonillion              10^30   (Meaningless to show in decimal form but the pattern continues)
    'Decillion              10^33
    'Undecillion            10^36
    'Duodecillion           10^39
    'Tredecillion           10^42
    'Continue this list:    http://www.olsenhome.com/bignumbers/
    
    'Constants
    Const validCharacters = "0123456789.-"  'Characters that are valid numerically
    
    'Declarations
    Dim strNumber As String
    Dim strName As String
    Dim strLeft As String, strRight As String
    Dim strPiece As String
    Dim strOne As String, strTen As String, strHundred As String
    Dim arrOnes, arrTens, arrOrders() As String, valOrder As Integer
    Dim i As Long
    Dim invalidNumber As Boolean
    
    'Store the input as a separate variable and remove any digit grouping
    strNumber = arabicNumberString
    strNumber = Replace(strNumber, application.ThousandsSeparator, "")
    
    'Check for errors (negative sign in the middle, more than one decimal point, any non-numeric characters)
    If InStr(2, strNumber, "-") > 1 Then invalidNumber = True
    If (Len(strNumber) - Len(Replace(strNumber, application.DecimalSeparator, ""))) > 1 Then invalidNumber = True
    For i = 1 To Len(strNumber)
        If InStr(1, validCharacters, Mid(strNumber, i, 1)) = 0 Then invalidNumber = True
    Next
    If invalidNumber Then SpellNumber = "(Not a valid number)": Exit Function
    
    'Remove the negative sign (it'll be checked later from the original input)
    If Left(strNumber, 1) = "-" Then strNumber = Mid(strNumber, 2)
    
    'Establish the arrays of name sections
    arrOnes = Array(Null, "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", _
        "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen")
    arrTens = Array(Null, "", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety")
    arrOrders = CreateArrOrders()   'Large and clumsy so it gets it's own function
    
    'Break it in half if it has a decimal place
    If InStr(1, strNumber, application.DecimalSeparator) > 0 Then
        strLeft = Left(strNumber, InStr(1, strNumber, application.DecimalSeparator) - 1)
        strRight = Mid(strNumber, InStr(1, strNumber, application.DecimalSeparator) + 1)
    Else
        strLeft = strNumber
        strRight = ""
    End If
    
    'Remove leading and trailing zeroes
    Do Until Left(strLeft, 1) <> "0"
        strLeft = Mid(strLeft, 2)
    Loop
    Do Until Right(strRight, 1) <> "0"
        strRight = Left(strRight, Len(strRight) - 1)
    Loop
    
    'Check if the number is too large on either side
    If ((Len(strLeft) - 1) / 3) > UBound(arrOrders) Or ((Len(strLeft) - 1) / 3) > UBound(arrOrders) Then
        SpellNumber = "Outside scope: Max 10^{± " & Format(UBound(arrOrders) * 3 - 3, "#" & application.ThousandsSeparator & "##0")
        SpellNumber = SpellNumber & "} [" & StrConv(arrOrders(UBound(arrOrders)), vbProperCase) & "(ths)]"
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    
    'Process the piece to the left of the decimal if it exists and isn't zero
    If Len(strLeft) > 0 Then
    If Len(Replace(strLeft, "0", "")) > 0 Then
        
        'Process each chunk one at a time in reverse
        valOrder = 1
        For i = 1 To UBound(arrOrders) * 3 + 1 Step 3
            
            'Break this chunk into pieces
            strPiece = Mid(StrReverse(strLeft), i, 3)
            strOne = Mid(strPiece, 1, 1)
            strTen = Mid(strPiece, 2, 1)
            strHundred = Mid(strPiece, 3, 1)
            
            'Check for zero
            If Val(strPiece) <> 0 Then
                'Add the order name
                If valOrder > 1 Then strName = arrOrders(valOrder) & " " & strName
                
                'Add the teens name or the tens / ones names
                If Val(strTen) <= 1 Then
                    strName = arrOnes(Val(strTen & strOne)) & " " & strName
                Else
                    strName = arrTens(Val(strTen)) & "-" & arrOnes(Val(strOne)) & " " & strName
                End If
                
                'Add the hundreds name
                If Val(strHundred) > 0 Then
                    strName = arrOnes(Val(strHundred)) & " hundred " & strName
                End If
            End If
            
            'Exit Early
            If i > Len(strLeft) Then Exit For
            
            'Increment
            valOrder = valOrder + 1
            
        Next
        
    End If
    End If
    
    'Process the piece to the right of the decimal if it exists and isn't zero
    If Len(strRight) > 0 Then
    If Len(Replace(strRight, "0", "")) > 0 Then

        'Add the decimal designator
        strName = strName & " and "
        
        'Check for small values
        If Len(strRight) = 1 Then
            strName = strName & arrOnes(Val(strRight)) & " tenth"
            If strRight <> "1" Then strName = strName & "s"
        ElseIf Len(strRight) = 2 Then
            strName = strName & SpellNumber(strRight) & " hundredths"
        Else
            strName = strName & SpellNumber(strRight)
            valOrder = Len(strRight) + 1
            valOrder = (valOrder - (valOrder Mod 3)) / 3 + 1
            strName = strName & " " & arrOrders(valOrder) & "ths"
        End If

    End If
    End If
    
    'Establish if it's negative
    If Left(arabicNumberString, 1) = "-" Then strName = "Negative " & strName
    
    'Cleanup
    strName = Replace(strName, "- ", " ")       'Removes err when tens > 1 and ones = 0 (e.g. "twenty-")
    strName = Trim(strName)                     'Removes leading and trailing spaces just in case
    strName = StrConv(strName, conversionCase)  'Applies casing to the string
    Do Until InStr(1, strName, "  ") = 0
        strName = Replace(strName, "  ", " ")   'Removes double spaces just in case
    Loop
    
    'Return the number
    SpellNumber = strName
    
End Function



Private Function CreateArrOrders() As String()

    Dim arrOrders(1 To 1005) As String

    arrOrders(2) = "thousand":  arrOrders(3) = "million":   arrOrders(4) = "billion":   arrOrders(5) = "trillion":  arrOrders(6) = "quadrillion":   arrOrders(7) = "quintillion":   arrOrders(8) = "sextillion":    arrOrders(9) = "septillion":    arrOrders(10) = "octillion":    arrOrders(11) = "nonillion":    arrOrders(12) = "decillion":    arrOrders(13) = "undecillion":  arrOrders(14) = "duodecillion": arrOrders(15) = "tredecillion":
    'Et cetera based on the source list / other answers. Too long to fit all in one posting on SuperUser.
    
    CreateArrOrders = arrOrders()

End Function
```

Comment: There probably isn't a lot of call for more than a few percent of these magnitudes.  For example, the number of atoms in the universe is a two digit magnitude.  Well, unless you're talking about what the US national debt will be in a few years.

Comment: @fixer1234 I'd wager that you are absolutely correct for almost every application. However, I'm a completionist. What if someone wants to use this to spell out [Graham's Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Graham%27s_number)? (Not that they *would*, mind you, because they'd have to compute it first.)

Comment: With some tweaks, it could even spell out *googolplex*, but it would be difficult to create the input!

Comment: @Gary'sStudent That would be a special case, wouldn't it? It's 10^100 which is outside the typical orders of magnitude as it's not a multiple of 3. You could do it but I opted for the easier, "official" format for numbers.

Comment: A *googol* is 10^100, that is **1** followed by 100 zeros.............a *googolplex* is a **1** followed by a googol number of zeros.  This far exceeds the limit to an Excel String variable!

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Ah, good point... That would require breaking the string into pieces and passing them to the function as an array of strings that were... long.

Comment: This code has a lot of issues, I am not sure where to start, but I am going to try to clean it up due to the fact I somehow actually need this functionality in Excel/VBA.   As just one example, where is `decimalMark` declared or set? Why are we taking in a parameter called `arabicNumberString` as a `String` and then immediately ... welll, "converting" it to a string (it already is a string)?  `strNumber = CStr(arabicNumberString)`  Too many issues to mention, I'll try to post a cleaned up version.

Comment: Just try to put `Option Explicit` at the top of this, which should **always** be used, and you'll see the number of variables that are not declared but still attempted to be used.  `digitGroupSeparator`, `decimalMark`, `validCharacters` ...

Comment: @Patrick Good, thanks! I haven't revisited this code in a long time and I'm sure it's lacking. If you post a better version here, I'll mark it accepted so future users see yours.

Comment: @EngineerToast Yep, wasn't a jab at you trying to help out.  I just started to get confused really quickly due to all the variables that were in code but were not declared or set anywhere.  `Option Explicit` always :)  I'll post an update in a bit.

Comment: @Patrick It turns out that I *had* used 'Option Explicit' and declared the missing variables but the function was in a module with other functions and I just forgot to copy the header information when I posted the code. A glaring error, really.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I took the code by @EngineerToast and worked with that, as in principle it is correct but flawed (and does not produce the correct results).  I haven't touched VBA in literally a decade but I decided to drive in here because I needed this for a spreadsheet.

First order of business, we *need an `Option Explicit` at the top*!  Never bother writing a single line of code without that.

That resulted in these types of errors, so I just commented out the lines that were doing nothing anyway.

[image: Not Defined #1]

I moved the sanitization process to a separate function.  All of this dealing with decimal separators and the like shouldn't be needed.  We just want the digits, so we strip the rest.

After all that, the code I wrote was still differing from the code above, but I verified that the results I am getting from my version match up with both Wolfram Alpha and Wikipedia's Large Number Names listing.

[image: Results of the Two Projects]

It does work on the little numbers too:

[image: Smaller Numbers]

Let me know if I'm missing anything.  This should be called via a cell with the following function:

> =NumberToName(TEXT(**B8**, "0"))

Where `B8` here is the numerical value you want to convert.  In my case, if B8 was "=211*(10^51)", the result of `=NumberToName(TEXT(B8, "0"))` would be:

> Two Hundred Eleven Sedecillion

Anyway, here's the modified code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function NumberToName(ByVal strNumber As String, Optional conversionCase As VbStrConv = vbProperCase) As String

    ' Remove seperators, white space, and anything else that is not needed
    strNumber = ExtractNumbers(strNumber)

    ' Don't do anything if we don't have a anything
    If (Len(strNumber) = 0) Then
        Exit Function
    End If

    'Establish the arrays of name sections
    Dim arrOnes: arrOnes = Array(Null, "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", _
        "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen")

    Dim arrTens: arrTens = Array(Null, "", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety")

    ' Get our huge array of orders of magnitutde
    Dim arrOrders() As String: arrOrders = GetMagnitudeArray()

    Dim prefixIncrement As Integer: prefixIncrement = 1

    Dim i As Long
    Dim strName As String

    'Process each chunk one at a time in reverse
    For i = 1 To ((UBound(arrOrders) * 3) + 1) Step 3

          'Break this chunk into pieces
          Dim strPiece As String: strPiece = Mid(StrReverse(strNumber), i, 3)

          'Check for zero
          If (Val(strPiece) <> 0) Then

          Dim strOne As String: strOne = Mid(strPiece, 1, 1)
          Dim hasOnes As Boolean: hasOnes = (Val(strOne) > 0)

          Dim strTen As String: strTen = Mid(strPiece, 2, 1)
          Dim hasTens As Boolean: hasTens = (Val(strTen) > 0)

          Dim strHundred As String: strHundred = Mid(strPiece, 3, 1)
          Dim hasHundreds As Boolean: hasHundreds = (Val(strHundred) > 0)

            'Add the order name
            If ((prefixIncrement > 1) And (Len(strNumber) > 3)) Then
                strName = arrOrders(prefixIncrement) & " " & strName
            End If

            'Add the teens name or the tens / ones names
            If Val(strTen) <= 1 Then
                strName = arrOnes(Val(strTen & strOne)) & " " & strName
            ElseIf hasTens And Not hasOnes Then
                strName = arrTens(Val(strTen)) & " " & strName
            Else
                strName = arrTens(Val(strTen)) & "-" & arrOnes(Val(strOne)) & " " & strName
            End If

            'Add the hundreds name
            If Val(strHundred) > 0 Then
                strName = arrOnes(Val(strHundred)) & " hundred " & strName
            End If

        End If

        prefixIncrement = prefixIncrement + 1

    Next

    'Cleanup
    strName = Replace(strName, "- ", " ")       'Removes err when tens > 1 and ones = 0 (e.g. "twenty-")
    strName = Trim(strName)                     'Removes leading and trailing spaces just in case
    strName = StrConv(strName, conversionCase)  'Applies casing to the string

    strName = Replace(strName, "  ", " ")   'Removes double spaces

    'Return the number
    NumberToName = strName


End Function

Private Function GetMagnitudeArray() As String()

    Dim arrOrders(1 To 1005) As String

    arrOrders(2) = "thousand":  arrOrders(3) = "million":   arrOrders(4) = "billion": 

<SNIP etc etc>

    GetMagnitudeArray = arrOrders()

End Function

Function ExtractNumbers(strText As String) As String

    Dim i As Integer, outputString As String

    For i = 1 To Len(strText)

        If IsNumeric(Mid(strText, i, 1)) Then
            outputString = outputString & Mid(strText, i, 1)
        End If

    Next i

    ExtractNumbers = outputString

End Function
```

Comment: I've reworked my own code based on some of your comments and changes. I especially like using a counter to get the name for the order of magnitude instead of trying to calculate based on the iteration number. Two things mine can do that yours can't, though, are negative number and decimal places. You may not need that for your application, though, so it makes sense to leave them out. The best thing was that, while looking for improvements, I realized I could recurse for the decimal places name instead of the mess I had before.

Comment: @EngineerToast Oops, yes, you're exactly right.  For my project I was working with large integers (no decimal places) and no negatives, so that got stripped.  I've actually added additional functionality to due to need, by adding a new optional parameter (original result by default).  It allows it to display `68.42 Quattuordecillion` instead of `Sixty-eight Quattuordecillion Four Hundred Twenty Tredecillion `.  Maybe I'll throw it up on my GitHub account, as I've cleaned it up as best I can and am getting accurate results.

Answer (score 0):

### ANSWER PART 2 of 3

Here is the more of the definition for arrOrders. You can copy as much or as little as desired.

```
arrOrders(16) = "quattuordecillion":    arrOrders(17) = "quindecillion":    arrOrders(18) = "sedecillion":  arrOrders(19) = "septendecillion":  arrOrders(20) = "octodecillion":    arrOrders(21) = "novendecillion":   arrOrders(22) = "vigintillion": arrOrders(23) = "unvigintillion":   arrOrders(24) = "duovigintillion":  arrOrders(25) = "tresvigintillion": arrOrders(26) = "quattuorvigintillion": arrOrders(27) = "quinvigintillion": arrOrders(28) = "sesvigintillion":  arrOrders(29) = "septemvigintillion":   arrOrders(30) = "octovigintillion":
arrOrders(31) = "novemvigintillion":    arrOrders(32) = "trigintillion":    arrOrders(33) = "untrigintillion":  arrOrders(34) = "duotrigintillion": arrOrders(35) = "trestrigintillion":    arrOrders(36) = "quattuortrigintillion":    arrOrders(37) = "quintrigintillion":    arrOrders(38) = "sestrigintillion": arrOrders(39) = "septentrigintillion":  arrOrders(40) = "octotrigintillion":    arrOrders(41) = "noventrigintillion":   arrOrders(42) = "quadragintillion": arrOrders(43) = "unquadragintillion":   arrOrders(44) = "duoquadragintillion":  arrOrders(45) = "tresquadragintillion":
arrOrders(46) = "quattuorquadragintillion": arrOrders(47) = "quindragintillion":    arrOrders(48) = "sesquadragintillion":  arrOrders(49) = "septenquadragintillion":   arrOrders(50) = "octoquadragintillion": arrOrders(51) = "novenquadragintillion":    arrOrders(52) = "quinquagintillion":    arrOrders(53) = "unquinquagintillion":  arrOrders(54) = "duoquinquagintillion": arrOrders(55) = "tresquinquagintillion":    arrOrders(56) = "quattuorquinquagintillion":    arrOrders(57) = "quinquinquagintillion":    arrOrders(58) = "sesquinquagintillion": arrOrders(59) = "septenquinquagintillion":  arrOrders(60) = "octoquinquagintillion":
arrOrders(61) = "novenquinquagintillion":   arrOrders(62) = "sexagintillion":   arrOrders(63) = "unsexagintillion": arrOrders(64) = "duosexagintillion":    arrOrders(65) = "tresexagintillion":    arrOrders(66) = "quattuorsexagintillion":   arrOrders(67) = "quinsexagintillion":   arrOrders(68) = "sesexagintillion": arrOrders(69) = "septensexagintillion": arrOrders(70) = "octosexagintillion":   arrOrders(71) = "novensexagintillion":  arrOrders(72) = "septuagintillion": arrOrders(73) = "unseptuagintillion":   arrOrders(74) = "duoseptuagintillion":  arrOrders(75) = "treseptuagintillion":
arrOrders(76) = "quattuorseptuagintillion": arrOrders(77) = "quinseptuagintillion": arrOrders(78) = "seseptuagintillion":   arrOrders(79) = "septenseptuagintillion":   arrOrders(80) = "octoseptuagintillion": arrOrders(81) = "novenseptuagintillion":    arrOrders(82) = "octogintillion":   arrOrders(83) = "unoctogintillion": arrOrders(84) = "duooctogintillion":    arrOrders(85) = "tresoctogintillion":   arrOrders(86) = "quattuoroctogintillion":   arrOrders(87) = "quinoctogintillion":   arrOrders(88) = "sexoctogintillion":    arrOrders(89) = "septemoctogintillion": arrOrders(90) = "octooctogintillion":
arrOrders(91) = "novemoctogintillion":  arrOrders(92) = "nonagintillion":   arrOrders(93) = "unnonagintillion": arrOrders(94) = "duononagintillion":    arrOrders(95) = "trenonagintillion":    arrOrders(96) = "quattuornonagintillion":   arrOrders(97) = "quinnonagintillion":   arrOrders(98) = "senonagintillion": arrOrders(99) = "septenonagintillion":  arrOrders(100) = "octononagintillion":  arrOrders(101) = "novenonagintillion":  arrOrders(102) = "centillion":  arrOrders(103) = "uncentillion":    arrOrders(104) = "duocentillion":   arrOrders(105) = "trescentillion":
arrOrders(106) = "quattuorcentillion":  arrOrders(107) = "quincentillion":  arrOrders(108) = "sexcentillion":   arrOrders(109) = "septencentillion":    arrOrders(110) = "octocentillion":  arrOrders(111) = "novencentillion": arrOrders(112) = "decicentillion":  arrOrders(113) = "undecicentillion":    arrOrders(114) = "duodecicentillion":   arrOrders(115) = "tredecicentillion":   arrOrders(116) = "quattuordecicentillion":  arrOrders(117) = "quindecicentillion":  arrOrders(118) = "sedecicentillion":    arrOrders(119) = "septendecicentillion":    arrOrders(120) = "octodecicentillion":
arrOrders(121) = "novendecicentillion": arrOrders(122) = "viginticentillion":   arrOrders(123) = "unviginticentillion": arrOrders(124) = "duoviginticentillion":    arrOrders(125) = "tresviginticentillion":   arrOrders(126) = "quattuorviginticentillion":   arrOrders(127) = "quinviginticentillion":   arrOrders(128) = "sesviginticentillion":    arrOrders(129) = "septemviginticentillion": arrOrders(130) = "octoviginticentillion":   arrOrders(131) = "novemviginticentillion":  arrOrders(132) = "trigintacentillion":  arrOrders(133) = "untrigintacentillion":    arrOrders(134) = "duotrigintacentillion":   arrOrders(135) = "trestrigintacentillion":
arrOrders(136) = "quattuortrigintacentillion":  arrOrders(137) = "quintrigintacentillion":  arrOrders(138) = "sestrigintacentillion":   arrOrders(139) = "septentrigintacentillion":    arrOrders(140) = "octotrigintacentillion":  arrOrders(141) = "noventrigintacentillion": arrOrders(142) = "quadragintacentillion":   arrOrders(143) = "unquadragintacentillion": arrOrders(144) = "duoquadragintacentillion":    arrOrders(145) = "tresquadragintacentillion":   arrOrders(146) = "quattuorquadragintacentillion":   arrOrders(147) = "quinquadragintacentillion":   arrOrders(148) = "sesquadragintacentillion":    arrOrders(149) = "septenquadragintacentillion": arrOrders(150) = "octoquadragintacentillion":
arrOrders(151) = "novenquadragintacentillion":  arrOrders(152) = "quinquagintacentillion":  arrOrders(153) = "unquinquagintacentillion":    arrOrders(154) = "duoquinquagintacentillion":   arrOrders(155) = "tresquinquagintacentillion":  arrOrders(156) = "quattuorquinquagintacentillion":  arrOrders(157) = "quinquinquagintacentillion":  arrOrders(158) = "sesquinquagintacentillion":   arrOrders(159) = "septenquinquagintacentillion":    arrOrders(160) = "octoquinquagintacentillion":  arrOrders(161) = "novenquinquagintacentillion": arrOrders(162) = "sexagintacentillion": arrOrders(163) = "unsexagintacentillion":   arrOrders(164) = "duosexagintacentillion":  arrOrders(165) = "tresexagintacentillion":
arrOrders(166) = "quattuorsexagintacentillion": arrOrders(167) = "quinsexagintacentillion": arrOrders(168) = "sesexagintacentillion":   arrOrders(169) = "septensexagintacentillion":   arrOrders(170) = "octosexagintacentillion": arrOrders(171) = "novensexagintacentillion":    arrOrders(172) = "septuagintacentillion":   arrOrders(173) = "unseptuagintacentillion": arrOrders(174) = "duoseptuagintacentillion":    arrOrders(175) = "treseptuagintacentillion":    arrOrders(176) = "quattuorseptuagintacentillion":   arrOrders(177) = "quinseptuagintacentillion":   arrOrders(178) = "seseptuagintacentillion": arrOrders(179) = "septenseptuagintacentillion": arrOrders(180) = "octoseptuagintacentillion":
arrOrders(181) = "novenseptuagintacentillion":  arrOrders(182) = "octogintacentillion": arrOrders(183) = "unoctogintacentillion":   arrOrders(184) = "duooctogintacentillion":  arrOrders(185) = "tresoctogintacentillion": arrOrders(186) = "quattuoroctogintacentillion": arrOrders(187) = "quinoctogintacentillion": arrOrders(188) = "sexoctogintacentillion":  arrOrders(189) = "septemoctogintacentillion":   arrOrders(190) = "octooctogintacentillion": arrOrders(191) = "novemoctogintacentillion":    arrOrders(192) = "nonagintacentillion": arrOrders(193) = "unnonagintacentillion":   arrOrders(194) = "duononagintacentillion":  arrOrders(195) = "trenonagintacentillion":
arrOrders(196) = "quattuornonagintacentillion": arrOrders(197) = "quinnonagintacentillion": arrOrders(198) = "senonagintacentillion":   arrOrders(199) = "septenonagintacentillion":    arrOrders(200) = "octononagintacentillion": arrOrders(201) = "novenonagintacentillion": arrOrders(202) = "ducentillion":    arrOrders(203) = "unducentillion":  arrOrders(204) = "duoducentillion": arrOrders(205) = "treducentillion": arrOrders(206) = "quattuorducentillion":    arrOrders(207) = "quinducentillion":    arrOrders(208) = "seducentillion":  arrOrders(209) = "septenducentillion":  arrOrders(210) = "octoducentillion":
arrOrders(211) = "novenducentillion":   arrOrders(212) = "deciducentillion":    arrOrders(213) = "undeciducentillion":  arrOrders(214) = "duodeciducentillion": arrOrders(215) = "tredeciducentillion": arrOrders(216) = "quattuordeciducentillion":    arrOrders(217) = "quindeciducentillion":    arrOrders(218) = "sedeciducentillion":  arrOrders(219) = "septendeciducentillion":  arrOrders(220) = "octodeciducentillion":    arrOrders(221) = "novendeciducentillion":   arrOrders(222) = "vigintiducentillion": arrOrders(223) = "unvigintiducentillion":   arrOrders(224) = "duovigintiducentillion":  arrOrders(225) = "tresvigintiducentillion":
arrOrders(226) = "quattuorvigintiducentillion": arrOrders(227) = "quinvigintiducentillion": arrOrders(228) = "sesvigintiducentillion":  arrOrders(229) = "septemvigintiducentillion":   arrOrders(230) = "octovigintiducentillion": arrOrders(231) = "novemvigintiducentillion":    arrOrders(232) = "trigintaducentillion":    arrOrders(233) = "untrigintaducentillion":  arrOrders(234) = "duotrigintaducentillion": arrOrders(235) = "trestrigintaducentillion":    arrOrders(236) = "quattuortrigintaducentillion":    arrOrders(237) = "quintrigintaducentillion":    arrOrders(238) = "sestrigintaducentillion": arrOrders(239) = "septentrigintaducentillion":  arrOrders(240) = "octotrigintaducentillion":
arrOrders(241) = "noventrigintaducentillion":   arrOrders(242) = "quadragintaducentillion": arrOrders(243) = "unquadragintaducentillion":   arrOrders(244) = "duoquadragintaducentillion":  arrOrders(245) = "tresquadragintaducentillion": arrOrders(246) = "quattuorquadragintaducentillion": arrOrders(247) = "quinquadragintaducentillion": arrOrders(248) = "sesquadragintaducentillion":  arrOrders(249) = "septenquadragintaducentillion":   arrOrders(250) = "octoquadragintaducentillion": arrOrders(251) = "novenquadragintaducentillion":    arrOrders(252) = "quinquagintaducentillion":    arrOrders(253) = "unquinquagintaducentillion":  arrOrders(254) = "duoquinquagintaducentillion": arrOrders(255) = "tresquinquagintaducentillion":
arrOrders(256) = "quattuorquinquagintaducentillion":    arrOrders(257) = "quinquinquagintaducentillion":    arrOrders(258) = "sesquinquagintaducentillion": arrOrders(259) = "septenquinquagintaducentillion":  arrOrders(260) = "octoquinquagintaducentillion":    arrOrders(261) = "novenquinquagintaducentillion":   arrOrders(262) = "sexagintaducentillion":   arrOrders(263) = "unsexagintaducentillion": arrOrders(264) = "duosexagintaducentillion":    arrOrders(265) = "tresexagintaducentillion":    arrOrders(266) = "quattuorsexagintaducentillion":   arrOrders(267) = "quinsexagintaducentillion":   arrOrders(268) = "sesexagintaducentillion": arrOrders(269) = "septensexagintaducentillion": arrOrders(270) = "octosexagintaducentillion":
arrOrders(271) = "novensexagintaducentillion":  arrOrders(272) = "septuagintaducentillion": arrOrders(273) = "unseptuagintaducentillion":   arrOrders(274) = "duoseptuagintaducentillion":  arrOrders(275) = "treseptuagintaducentillion":  arrOrders(276) = "quattuorseptuagintaducentillion": arrOrders(277) = "quinseptuagintaducentillion": arrOrders(278) = "seseptuagintaducentillion":   arrOrders(279) = "septenseptuagintaducentillion":   arrOrders(280) = "octoseptuagintaducentillion": arrOrders(281) = "novenseptuagintaducentillion":    arrOrders(282) = "octogintaducentillion":   arrOrders(283) = "unoctogintaducentillion": arrOrders(284) = "duooctogintaducentillion":    arrOrders(285) = "tresoctogintaducentillion":
arrOrders(286) = "quattuoroctogintaducentillion":   arrOrders(287) = "quinoctogintaducentillion":   arrOrders(288) = "sexoctogintaducentillion":    arrOrders(289) = "septemoctogintaducentillion": arrOrders(290) = "octooctogintaducentillion":   arrOrders(291) = "novemoctogintaducentillion":  arrOrders(292) = "nonagintaducentillion":   arrOrders(293) = "unnonagintaducentillion": arrOrders(294) = "duononagintaducentillion":    arrOrders(295) = "trenonagintaducentillion":    arrOrders(296) = "quattuornonagintaducentillion":   arrOrders(297) = "quinnonagintaducentillion":   arrOrders(298) = "senonagintaducentillion": arrOrders(299) = "septenonagintaducentillion":  arrOrders(300) = "octononagintaducentillion":
arrOrders(301) = "novenonagintaducentillion":   arrOrders(302) = "trecentillion":   arrOrders(303) = "untrecentillion": arrOrders(304) = "duotrecentillion":    arrOrders(305) = "trestrecentillion":   arrOrders(306) = "quattuortrecentillion":   arrOrders(307) = "quintrecentillion":   arrOrders(308) = "sestrecentillion":    arrOrders(309) = "septentrecentillion": arrOrders(310) = "octotrecentillion":   arrOrders(311) = "noventrecentillion":  arrOrders(312) = "decitrecentillion":   arrOrders(313) = "undecitrecentillion": arrOrders(314) = "duodecitrecentillion":    arrOrders(315) = "tredecitrecentillion":
arrOrders(316) = "quattuordecitrecentillion":   arrOrders(317) = "quindecitrecentillion":   arrOrders(318) = "sedecitrecentillion": arrOrders(319) = "septendecitrecentillion": arrOrders(320) = "octodecitrecentillion":   arrOrders(321) = "novendecitrecentillion":  arrOrders(322) = "vigintitrecentillion":    arrOrders(323) = "unvigintitrecentillion":  arrOrders(324) = "duovigintitrecentillion": arrOrders(325) = "tresvigintitrecentillion":    arrOrders(326) = "quattuorvigintitrecentillion":    arrOrders(327) = "quinvigintitrecentillion":    arrOrders(328) = "sesvigintitrecentillion": arrOrders(329) = "septemvigintitrecentillion":  arrOrders(330) = "octovigintitrecentillion":
arrOrders(331) = "novemvigintitrecentillion":   arrOrders(332) = "trigintatrecentillion":   arrOrders(333) = "untrigintatrecentillion": arrOrders(334) = "duotrigintatrecentillion":    arrOrders(335) = "trestrigintatrecentillion":   arrOrders(336) = "quattuortrigintatrecentillion":   arrOrders(337) = "quintrigintatrecentillion":   arrOrders(338) = "sestrigintatrecentillion":    arrOrders(339) = "septentrigintatrecentillion": arrOrders(340) = "octotrigintatrecentillion":   arrOrders(341) = "noventrigintatrecentillion":  arrOrders(342) = "quadragintatrecentillion":    arrOrders(343) = "unquadragintatrecentillion":  arrOrders(344) = "duoquadragintatrecentillion": arrOrders(345) = "tresquadragintatrecentillion":
arrOrders(346) = "quattuorquadragintatrecentillion":    arrOrders(347) = "quinquadragintatrecentillion":    arrOrders(348) = "sesquadragintatrecentillion": arrOrders(349) = "septenquadragintatrecentillion":  arrOrders(350) = "octoquadragintatrecentillion":    arrOrders(351) = "novenquadragintatrecentillion":   arrOrders(352) = "quinquagintatrecentillion":   arrOrders(353) = "unquinquagintatrecentillion": arrOrders(354) = "duoquinquagintatrecentillion":    arrOrders(355) = "tresquinquagintatrecentillion":   arrOrders(356) = "quattuorquinquagintatrecentillion":   arrOrders(357) = "quinquinquagintatrecentillion":   arrOrders(358) = "sesquinquagintatrecentillion":    arrOrders(359) = "septenquinquagintatrecentillion": arrOrders(360) = "octoquinquagintatrecentillion":
arrOrders(361) = "novenquinquagintatrecentillion":  arrOrders(362) = "sexagintatrecentillion":  arrOrders(363) = "unsexagintatrecentillion":    arrOrders(364) = "duosexagintatrecentillion":   arrOrders(365) = "tresexagintatrecentillion":   arrOrders(366) = "quattuorsexagintatrecentillion":  arrOrders(367) = "quinsexagintatrecentillion":  arrOrders(368) = "sesexagintatrecentillion":    arrOrders(369) = "septensexagintatrecentillion":    arrOrders(370) = "octosexagintatrecentillion":  arrOrders(371) = "novensexagintatrecentillion": arrOrders(372) = "septuagintatrecentillion":    arrOrders(373) = "unseptuagintatrecentillion":  arrOrders(374) = "duoseptuagintatrecentillion": arrOrders(375) = "treseptuagintatrecentillion":
arrOrders(376) = "quattuorseptuagintatrecentillion":    arrOrders(377) = "quinseptuagintatrecentillion":    arrOrders(378) = "seseptuagintatrecentillion":  arrOrders(379) = "septenseptuagintatrecentillion":  arrOrders(380) = "octoseptuagintatrecentillion":    arrOrders(381) = "novenseptuagintatrecentillion":   arrOrders(382) = "octogintatrecentillion":  arrOrders(383) = "unoctogintatrecentillion":    arrOrders(384) = "duooctogintatrecentillion":   arrOrders(385) = "tresoctogintatrecentillion":  arrOrders(386) = "quattuoroctogintatrecentillion":  arrOrders(387) = "quinoctogintatrecentillion":  arrOrders(388) = "sexoctogintatrecentillion":   arrOrders(389) = "septemoctogintatrecentillion":    arrOrders(390) = "octooctogintatrecentillion":
arrOrders(391) = "novemoctogintatrecentillion": arrOrders(392) = "nonagintatrecentillion":  arrOrders(393) = "unnonagintatrecentillion":    arrOrders(394) = "duononagintatrecentillion":   arrOrders(395) = "trenonagintatrecentillion":   arrOrders(396) = "quattuornonagintatrecentillion":  arrOrders(397) = "quinnonagintatrecentillion":  arrOrders(398) = "senonagintatrecentillion":    arrOrders(399) = "septenonagintatrecentillion": arrOrders(400) = "octononagintatrecentillion":  arrOrders(401) = "novenonagintatrecentillion":  arrOrders(402) = "quadringentillion":   arrOrders(403) = "unquadringentillion": arrOrders(404) = "duoquadringentillion":    arrOrders(405) = "tresquadringentillion":
arrOrders(406) = "quattuorquadringentillion":   arrOrders(407) = "quinquadringentillion":   arrOrders(408) = "sesquadringentillion":    arrOrders(409) = "septenquadringentillion": arrOrders(410) = "octoquadringentillion":   arrOrders(411) = "novenquadringentillion":  arrOrders(412) = "deciquadringentillion":   arrOrders(413) = "undeciquadringentillion": arrOrders(414) = "duodeciquadringentillion":    arrOrders(415) = "tredeciquadringentillion":    arrOrders(416) = "quattuordeciquadringentillion":   arrOrders(417) = "quindeciquadringentillion":   arrOrders(418) = "sedeciquadringentillion": arrOrders(419) = "septendeciquadringentillion": arrOrders(420) = "octodeciquadringentillion":
arrOrders(421) = "novendeciquadringentillion":  arrOrders(422) = "vigintiquadringentillion":    arrOrders(423) = "unvigintiquadringentillion":  arrOrders(424) = "duovigintiquadringentillion": arrOrders(425) = "tresvigintiquadringentillion":    arrOrders(426) = "quattuorvigintiquadringentillion":    arrOrders(427) = "quinvigintiquadringentillion":    arrOrders(428) = "sesvigintiquadringentillion": arrOrders(429) = "septemvigintiquadringentillion":  arrOrders(430) = "octovigintiquadringentillion":    arrOrders(431) = "novemvigintiquadringentillion":   arrOrders(432) = "trigintaquadringentillion":   arrOrders(433) = "untrigintaquadringentillion": arrOrders(434) = "duotrigintaquadringentillion":    arrOrders(435) = "trestrigintaquadringentillion":
arrOrders(436) = "quattuortrigintaquadringentillion":   arrOrders(437) = "quintrigintaquadringentillion":   arrOrders(438) = "sestrigintaquadringentillion":    arrOrders(439) = "septentrigintaquadringentillion": arrOrders(440) = "octotrigintaquadringentillion":   arrOrders(441) = "noventrigintaquadringentillion":  arrOrders(442) = "quadragintaquadringentillion":    arrOrders(443) = "unquadragintaquadringentillion":  arrOrders(444) = "duoquadragintaquadringentillion": arrOrders(445) = "tresquadragintaquadringentillion":    arrOrders(446) = "quattuorquadragintaquadringentillion":    arrOrders(447) = "quinquadragintaquadringentillion":    arrOrders(448) = "sesquadragintaquadringentillion": arrOrders(449) = "septenquadragintaquadringentillion":  arrOrders(450) = "octoquadragintaquadringentillion":
arrOrders(451) = "novenquadragintaquadringentillion":   arrOrders(452) = "quinquagintaquadringentillion":   arrOrders(453) = "unquinquagintaquadringentillion": arrOrders(454) = "duoquinquagintaquadringentillion":    arrOrders(455) = "tresquinquagintaquadringentillion":   arrOrders(456) = "quattuorquinquagintaquadringentillion":   arrOrders(457) = "quinquinquagintaquadringentillion":   arrOrders(458) = "sesquinquagintaquadringentillion":    arrOrders(459) = "septenquinquagintaquadringentillion": arrOrders(460) = "octoquinquagintaquadringentillion":   arrOrders(461) = "novenquinquagintaquadringentillion":  arrOrders(462) = "sexagintaquadringentillion":  arrOrders(463) = "unsexagintaquadringentillion":    arrOrders(464) = "duosexagintaquadringentillion":   arrOrders(465) = "tresexagintaquadringentillion":
arrOrders(466) = "quattuorsexagintaquadringentillion":  arrOrders(467) = "quinsexagintaquadringentillion":  arrOrders(468) = "sesexagintaquadringentillion":    arrOrders(469) = "septensexagintaquadringentillion":    arrOrders(470) = "octosexagintaquadringentillion":  arrOrders(471) = "novensexagintaquadringentillion": arrOrders(472) = "septuagintaquadringentillion":    arrOrders(473) = "unseptuagintaquadringentillion":  arrOrders(474) = "duoseptuagintaquadringentillion": arrOrders(475) = "treseptuagintaquadringentillion": arrOrders(476) = "quattuorseptuagintaquadringentillion":    arrOrders(477) = "quinseptuagintaquadringentillion":    arrOrders(478) = "seseptuagintaquadringentillion":  arrOrders(479) = "septenseptuagintaquadringentillion":  arrOrders(480) = "octoseptuagintaquadringentillion":
arrOrders(481) = "novenseptuagintaquadringentillion":   arrOrders(482) = "octogintaquadringentillion":  arrOrders(483) = "unoctogintaquadringentillion":    arrOrders(484) = "duooctogintaquadringentillion":   arrOrders(485) = "tresoctogintaquadringentillion":  arrOrders(486) = "quattuoroctogintaquadringentillion":  arrOrders(487) = "quinoctogintaquadringentillion":  arrOrders(488) = "sexoctogintaquadringentillion":   arrOrders(489) = "septemoctogintaquadringentillion":    arrOrders(490) = "octooctogintaquadringentillion":  arrOrders(491) = "novemoctogintaquadringentillion": arrOrders(492) = "nonagintaquadringentillion":  arrOrders(493) = "unnonagintaquadringentillion":    arrOrders(494) = "duononagintaquadringentillion":   arrOrders(495) = "trenonagintaquadringentillion":
arrOrders(496) = "quattuornonagintaquadringentillion":  arrOrders(497) = "quinnonagintaquadringentillion":  arrOrders(498) = "senonagintaquadringentillion":    arrOrders(499) = "septenonagintaquadringentillion": arrOrders(500) = "octononagintaquadringentillion":  arrOrders(501) = "novenonagintaquadringentillion":  arrOrders(502) = "quingentillion":  arrOrders(503) = "unquingentillion":    arrOrders(504) = "duoquingentillion":   arrOrders(505) = "tresquingentillion":  arrOrders(506) = "quattuorquingentillion":  arrOrders(507) = "quinquingentillion":  arrOrders(508) = "sesquingentillion":   arrOrders(509) = "septenquingentillion":    arrOrders(510) = "octoquingentillion":
arrOrders(511) = "novenquingentillion": arrOrders(512) = "deciquingentillion":  arrOrders(513) = "undeciquingentillion":    arrOrders(514) = "duodeciquingentillion":   arrOrders(515) = "tredeciquingentillion":   arrOrders(516) = "quattuordeciquingentillion":  arrOrders(517) = "quindeciquingentillion":  arrOrders(518) = "sedeciquingentillion":    arrOrders(519) = "septendeciquingentillion":    arrOrders(520) = "octodeciquingentillion":  arrOrders(521) = "novendeciquingentillion": arrOrders(522) = "vigintiquingentillion":   arrOrders(523) = "unvigintiquingentillion": arrOrders(524) = "duovigintiquingentillion":    arrOrders(525) = "tresvigintiquingentillion":
arrOrders(526) = "quattuorvigintiquingentillion":   arrOrders(527) = "quinvigintiquingentillion":   arrOrders(528) = "sesvigintiquingentillion":    arrOrders(529) = "septemvigintiquingentillion": arrOrders(530) = "octovigintiquingentillion":   arrOrders(531) = "novemvigintiquingentillion":  arrOrders(532) = "trigintaquingentillion":  arrOrders(533) = "untrigintaquingentillion":    arrOrders(534) = "duotrigintaquingentillion":   arrOrders(535) = "trestrigintaquingentillion":  arrOrders(536) = "quattuortrigintaquingentillion":  arrOrders(537) = "quintrigintaquingentillion":  arrOrders(538) = "sestrigintaquingentillion":   arrOrders(539) = "septentrigintaquingentillion":    arrOrders(540) = "octotrigintaquingentillion":
```

Answer (score 0):

### ANSWER PART 3 of 3

Here is the rest of the definition for arrOrders. You can copy as much or as little as desired.

```
arrOrders(541) = "noventrigintaquingentillion": arrOrders(542) = "quadragintaquingentillion":   arrOrders(543) = "unquadragintaquingentillion": arrOrders(544) = "duoquadragintaquingentillion":    arrOrders(545) = "tresquadragintaquingentillion":   arrOrders(546) = "quattuorquadragintaquingentillion":   arrOrders(547) = "quinquadragintaquingentillion":   arrOrders(548) = "sesquadragintaquingentillion":    arrOrders(549) = "septenquadragintaquingentillion": arrOrders(550) = "octoquadragintaquingentillion":   arrOrders(551) = "novenquadragintaquingentillion":  arrOrders(552) = "quinquagintaquingentillion":  arrOrders(553) = "unquinquagintaquingentillion":    arrOrders(554) = "duoquinquagintaquingentillion":   arrOrders(555) = "tresquinquagintaquingentillion":
arrOrders(556) = "quattuorquinquagintaquingentillion":  arrOrders(557) = "quinquinquagintaquingentillion":  arrOrders(558) = "sesquinquagintaquingentillion":   arrOrders(559) = "septenquinquagintaquingentillion":    arrOrders(560) = "octoquinquagintaquingentillion":  arrOrders(561) = "novenquinquagintaquingentillion": arrOrders(562) = "sexagintaquingentillion": arrOrders(563) = "unsexagintaquingentillion":   arrOrders(564) = "duosexagintaquingentillion":  arrOrders(565) = "tresexagintaquingentillion":  arrOrders(566) = "quattuorsexagintaquingentillion": arrOrders(567) = "quinsexagintaquingentillion": arrOrders(568) = "sesexagintaquingentillion":   arrOrders(569) = "septensexagintaquingentillion":   arrOrders(570) = "octosexagintaquingentillion":
arrOrders(571) = "novensexagintaquingentillion":    arrOrders(572) = "septuagintaquingentillion":   arrOrders(573) = "unseptuagintaquingentillion": arrOrders(574) = "duoseptuagintaquingentillion":    arrOrders(575) = "treseptuagintaquingentillion":    arrOrders(576) = "quattuorseptuagintaquingentillion":   arrOrders(577) = "quinseptuagintaquingentillion":   arrOrders(578) = "seseptuagintaquingentillion": arrOrders(579) = "septenseptuagintaquingentillion": arrOrders(580) = "octoseptuagintaquingentillion":   arrOrders(581) = "novenseptuagintaquingentillion":  arrOrders(582) = "octogintaquingentillion": arrOrders(583) = "unoctogintaquingentillion":   arrOrders(584) = "duooctogintaquingentillion":  arrOrders(585) = "tresoctogintaquingentillion":
arrOrders(586) = "quattuoroctogintaquingentillion": arrOrders(587) = "quinoctogintaquingentillion": arrOrders(588) = "sexoctogintaquingentillion":  arrOrders(589) = "septemoctogintaquingentillion":   arrOrders(590) = "octooctogintaquingentillion": arrOrders(591) = "novemoctogintaquingentillion":    arrOrders(592) = "nonagintaquingentillion": arrOrders(593) = "unnonagintaquingentillion":   arrOrders(594) = "duononagintaquingentillion":  arrOrders(595) = "trenonagintaquingentillion":  arrOrders(596) = "quattuornonagintaquingentillion": arrOrders(597) = "quinnonagintaquingentillion": arrOrders(598) = "senonagintaquingentillion":   arrOrders(599) = "septenonagintaquingentillion":    arrOrders(600) = "octononagintaquingentillion":
arrOrders(601) = "novenonagintaquingentillion": arrOrders(602) = "sescentillion":   arrOrders(603) = "unsescentillion": arrOrders(604) = "duosescentillion":    arrOrders(605) = "tresescentillion":    arrOrders(606) = "quattuorsescentillion":   arrOrders(607) = "quinsescentillion":   arrOrders(608) = "sesescentillion": arrOrders(609) = "septensescentillion": arrOrders(610) = "octosescentillion":   arrOrders(611) = "novensescentillion":  arrOrders(612) = "decisescentillion":   arrOrders(613) = "undecisescentillion": arrOrders(614) = "duodecisescentillion":    arrOrders(615) = "tredecisescentillion":
arrOrders(616) = "quattuordecisescentillion":   arrOrders(617) = "quindecisescentillion":   arrOrders(618) = "sedecisescentillion": arrOrders(619) = "septendecisescentillion": arrOrders(620) = "octodecisescentillion":   arrOrders(621) = "novendecisescentillion":  arrOrders(622) = "vigintisescentillion":    arrOrders(623) = "unvigintisescentillion":  arrOrders(624) = "duovigintisescentillion": arrOrders(625) = "tresvigintisescentillion":    arrOrders(626) = "quattuorvigintisescentillion":    arrOrders(627) = "quinvigintisescentillion":    arrOrders(628) = "sesvigintisescentillion": arrOrders(629) = "septemvigintisescentillion":  arrOrders(630) = "octovigintisescentillion":
arrOrders(631) = "novemvigintisescentillion":   arrOrders(632) = "trigintasescentillion":   arrOrders(633) = "untrigintasescentillion": arrOrders(634) = "duotrigintasescentillion":    arrOrders(635) = "trestrigintasescentillion":   arrOrders(636) = "quattuortrigintasescentillion":   arrOrders(637) = "quintrigintasescentillion":   arrOrders(638) = "sestrigintasescentillion":    arrOrders(639) = "septentrigintasescentillion": arrOrders(640) = "octotrigintasescentillion":   arrOrders(641) = "noventrigintasescentillion":  arrOrders(642) = "quadragintasescentillion":    arrOrders(643) = "unquadragintasescentillion":  arrOrders(644) = "duoquadragintasescentillion": arrOrders(645) = "tresquadragintasescentillion":
arrOrders(646) = "quattuorquadragintasescentillion":    arrOrders(647) = "quinquadragintasescentillion":    arrOrders(648) = "sesquadragintasescentillion": arrOrders(649) = "septenquadragintasescentillion":  arrOrders(650) = "octoquadragintasescentillion":    arrOrders(651) = "novenquadragintasescentillion":   arrOrders(652) = "quinquagintasescentillion":   arrOrders(653) = "unquinquagintasescentillion": arrOrders(654) = "duoquinquagintasescentillion":    arrOrders(655) = "tresquinquagintasescentillion":   arrOrders(656) = "quattuorquinquagintasescentillion":   arrOrders(657) = "quinquinquagintasescentillion":   arrOrders(658) = "sesquinquagintasescentillion":    arrOrders(659) = "septenquinquagintasescentillion": arrOrders(660) = "octoquinquagintasescentillion":
arrOrders(661) = "novenquinquagintasescentillion":  arrOrders(662) = "sexagintasescentillion":  arrOrders(663) = "unsexagintasescentillion":    arrOrders(664) = "duosexagintasescentillion":   arrOrders(665) = "tresexagintasescentillion":   arrOrders(666) = "quattuorsexagintasescentillion":  arrOrders(667) = "quinsexagintasescentillion":  arrOrders(668) = "sesexagintasescentillion":    arrOrders(669) = "septensexagintasescentillion":    arrOrders(670) = "octosexagintasescentillion":  arrOrders(671) = "novensexagintasescentillion": arrOrders(672) = "septuagintasescentillion":    arrOrders(673) = "unseptuagintasescentillion":  arrOrders(674) = "duoseptuagintasescentillion": arrOrders(675) = "treseptuagintasescentillion":
arrOrders(676) = "quattuorseptuagintasescentillion":    arrOrders(677) = "quinseptuagintasescentillion":    arrOrders(678) = "seseptuagintasescentillion":  arrOrders(679) = "septenseptuagintasescentillion":  arrOrders(680) = "octoseptuagintasescentillion":    arrOrders(681) = "novenseptuagintasescentillion":   arrOrders(682) = "octogintasescentillion":  arrOrders(683) = "unoctogintasescentillion":    arrOrders(684) = "duooctogintasescentillion":   arrOrders(685) = "tresoctogintasescentillion":  arrOrders(686) = "quattuoroctogintasescentillion":  arrOrders(687) = "quinoctogintasescentillion":  arrOrders(688) = "sexoctogintasescentillion":   arrOrders(689) = "septemoctogintasescentillion":    arrOrders(690) = "octooctogintasescentillion":
arrOrders(691) = "novemoctogintasescentillion": arrOrders(692) = "nonagintasescentillion":  arrOrders(693) = "unnonagintasescentillion":    arrOrders(694) = "duononagintasescentillion":   arrOrders(695) = "trenonagintasescentillion":   arrOrders(696) = "quattuornonagintasescentillion":  arrOrders(697) = "quinnonagintasescentillion":  arrOrders(698) = "senonagintasescentillion":    arrOrders(699) = "septenonagintasescentillion": arrOrders(700) = "octononagintasescentillion":  arrOrders(701) = "novenonagintasescentillion":  arrOrders(702) = "septingentillion":    arrOrders(703) = "unseptingentillion":  arrOrders(704) = "duoseptingentillion": arrOrders(705) = "treseptingentillion":
arrOrders(706) = "quattuorseptingentillion":    arrOrders(707) = "quinseptingentillion":    arrOrders(708) = "seseptingentillion":  arrOrders(709) = "septenseptingentillion":  arrOrders(710) = "octoseptingentillion":    arrOrders(711) = "novenseptingentillion":   arrOrders(712) = "deciseptingentillion":    arrOrders(713) = "undeciseptingentillion":  arrOrders(714) = "duodeciseptingentillion": arrOrders(715) = "tredeciseptingentillion": arrOrders(716) = "quattuordeciseptingentillion":    arrOrders(717) = "quindeciseptingentillion":    arrOrders(718) = "sedeciseptingentillion":  arrOrders(719) = "septendeciseptingentillion":  arrOrders(720) = "octodeciseptingentillion":
arrOrders(721) = "novendeciseptingentillion":   arrOrders(722) = "vigintiseptingentillion": arrOrders(723) = "unvigintiseptingentillion":   arrOrders(724) = "duovigintiseptingentillion":  arrOrders(725) = "tresvigintiseptingentillion": arrOrders(726) = "quattuorvigintiseptingentillion": arrOrders(727) = "quinvigintiseptingentillion": arrOrders(728) = "sesvigintiseptingentillion":  arrOrders(729) = "septemvigintiseptingentillion":   arrOrders(730) = "octovigintiseptingentillion": arrOrders(731) = "novemvigintiseptingentillion":    arrOrders(732) = "trigintaseptingentillion":    arrOrders(733) = "untrigintaseptingentillion":  arrOrders(734) = "duotrigintaseptingentillion": arrOrders(735) = "trestrigintaseptingentillion":
arrOrders(736) = "quattuortrigintaseptingentillion":    arrOrders(737) = "quintrigintaseptingentillion":    arrOrders(738) = "sestrigintaseptingentillion": arrOrders(739) = "septentrigintaseptingentillion":  arrOrders(740) = "octotrigintaseptingentillion":    arrOrders(741) = "noventrigintaseptingentillion":   arrOrders(742) = "quadragintaseptingentillion": arrOrders(743) = "unquadragintaseptingentillion":   arrOrders(744) = "duoquadragintaseptingentillion":  arrOrders(745) = "tresquadragintaseptingentillion": arrOrders(746) = "quattuorquadragintaseptingentillion": arrOrders(747) = "quinquadragintaseptingentillion": arrOrders(748) = "sesquadragintaseptingentillion":  arrOrders(749) = "septenquadragintaseptingentillion":   arrOrders(750) = "octoquadragintaseptingentillion":
arrOrders(751) = "novenquadragintaseptingentillion":    arrOrders(752) = "quinquagintaseptingentillion":    arrOrders(753) = "unquinquagintaseptingentillion":  arrOrders(754) = "duoquinquagintaseptingentillion": arrOrders(755) = "tresquinquagintaseptingentillion":    arrOrders(756) = "quattuorquinquagintaseptingentillion":    arrOrders(757) = "quinquinquagintaseptingentillion":    arrOrders(758) = "sesquinquagintaseptingentillion": arrOrders(759) = "septenquinquagintaseptingentillion":  arrOrders(760) = "octoquinquagintaseptingentillion":    arrOrders(761) = "novenquinquagintaseptingentillion":   arrOrders(762) = "sexagintaseptingentillion":   arrOrders(763) = "unsexagintaseptingentillion": arrOrders(764) = "duosexagintaseptingentillion":    arrOrders(765) = "tresexagintaseptingentillion":
arrOrders(766) = "quattuorsexagintaseptingentillion":   arrOrders(767) = "quinsexagintaseptingentillion":   arrOrders(768) = "sesexagintaseptingentillion": arrOrders(769) = "septensexagintaseptingentillion": arrOrders(770) = "octosexagintaseptingentillion":   arrOrders(771) = "novensexagintaseptingentillion":  arrOrders(772) = "septuagintaseptingentillion": arrOrders(773) = "unseptuagintaseptingentillion":   arrOrders(774) = "duoseptuagintaseptingentillion":  arrOrders(775) = "treseptuagintaseptingentillion":  arrOrders(776) = "quattuorseptuagintaseptingentillion": arrOrders(777) = "quinseptuagintaseptingentillion": arrOrders(778) = "seseptuagintaseptingentillion":   arrOrders(779) = "septenseptuagintaseptingentillion":   arrOrders(780) = "octoseptuagintaseptingentillion":
arrOrders(781) = "novenseptuagintaseptingentillion":    arrOrders(782) = "octogintaseptingentillion":   arrOrders(783) = "unoctogintaseptingentillion": arrOrders(784) = "duooctogintaseptingentillion":    arrOrders(785) = "tresoctogintaseptingentillion":   arrOrders(786) = "quattuoroctogintaseptingentillion":   arrOrders(787) = "quinoctogintaseptingentillion":   arrOrders(788) = "sexoctogintaseptingentillion":    arrOrders(789) = "septemoctogintaseptingentillion": arrOrders(790) = "octooctogintaseptingentillion":   arrOrders(791) = "novemoctogintaseptingentillion":  arrOrders(792) = "nonagintaseptingentillion":   arrOrders(793) = "unnonagintaseptingentillion": arrOrders(794) = "duononagintaseptingentillion":    arrOrders(795) = "trenonagintaseptingentillion":
arrOrders(796) = "quattuornonagintaseptingentillion":   arrOrders(797) = "quinnonagintaseptingentillion":   arrOrders(798) = "senonagintaseptingentillion": arrOrders(799) = "septenonagintaseptingentillion":  arrOrders(800) = "octononagintaseptingentillion":   arrOrders(801) = "novenonagintaseptingentillion":   arrOrders(802) = "octingentillion": arrOrders(803) = "unoctingentillion":   arrOrders(804) = "duooctingentillion":  arrOrders(805) = "tresoctingentillion": arrOrders(806) = "quattuoroctingentillion": arrOrders(807) = "quinoctingentillion": arrOrders(808) = "sexoctingentillion":  arrOrders(809) = "septemoctingentillion":   arrOrders(810) = "octooctingentillion":
arrOrders(811) = "novemoctingentillion":    arrOrders(812) = "decioctingentillion": arrOrders(813) = "undecioctingentillion":   arrOrders(814) = "duodecioctingentillion":  arrOrders(815) = "tredecioctingentillion":  arrOrders(816) = "quattuordecioctingentillion": arrOrders(817) = "quindecioctingentillion": arrOrders(818) = "sedecioctingentillion":   arrOrders(819) = "septendecioctingentillion":   arrOrders(820) = "octodecioctingentillion": arrOrders(821) = "novendecioctingentillion":    arrOrders(822) = "vigintioctingentillion":  arrOrders(823) = "unvigintioctingentillion":    arrOrders(824) = "duovigintioctingentillion":   arrOrders(825) = "tresvigintioctingentillion":
arrOrders(826) = "quattuorvigintioctingentillion":  arrOrders(827) = "quinvigintioctingentillion":  arrOrders(828) = "sesvigintioctingentillion":   arrOrders(829) = "septemvigintioctingentillion":    arrOrders(830) = "octovigintioctingentillion":  arrOrders(831) = "novemvigintioctingentillion": arrOrders(832) = "trigintaoctingentillion": arrOrders(833) = "untrigintaoctingentillion":   arrOrders(834) = "duotrigintaoctingentillion":  arrOrders(835) = "trestrigintaoctingentillion": arrOrders(836) = "quattuortrigintaoctingentillion": arrOrders(837) = "quintrigintaoctingentillion": arrOrders(838) = "sestrigintaoctingentillion":  arrOrders(839) = "septentrigintaoctingentillion":   arrOrders(840) = "octotrigintaoctingentillion":
arrOrders(841) = "noventrigintaoctingentillion":    arrOrders(842) = "quadragintaoctingentillion":  arrOrders(843) = "unquadragintaoctingentillion":    arrOrders(844) = "duoquadragintaoctingentillion":   arrOrders(845) = "tresquadragintaoctingentillion":  arrOrders(846) = "quattuorquadragintaoctingentillion":  arrOrders(847) = "quinquadragintaoctingentillion":  arrOrders(848) = "sesquadragintaoctingentillion":   arrOrders(849) = "septenquadragintaoctingentillion":    arrOrders(850) = "octoquadragintaoctingentillion":  arrOrders(851) = "novenquadragintaoctingentillion": arrOrders(852) = "quinquagintaoctingentillion": arrOrders(853) = "unquinquagintaoctingentillion":   arrOrders(854) = "duoquinquagintaoctingentillion":  arrOrders(855) = "tresquinquagintaoctingentillion":
arrOrders(856) = "quattuorquinquagintaoctingentillion": arrOrders(857) = "quinquinquagintaoctingentillion": arrOrders(858) = "sesquinquagintaoctingentillion":  arrOrders(859) = "septenquinquagintaoctingentillion":   arrOrders(860) = "octoquinquagintaoctingentillion": arrOrders(861) = "novenquinquagintaoctingentillion":    arrOrders(862) = "sexagintaoctingentillion":    arrOrders(863) = "unsexagintaoctingentillion":  arrOrders(864) = "duosexagintaoctingentillion": arrOrders(865) = "tresexagintaoctingentillion": arrOrders(866) = "quattuorsexagintaoctingentillion":    arrOrders(867) = "quinsexagintaoctingentillion":    arrOrders(868) = "sesexagintaoctingentillion":  arrOrders(869) = "septensexagintaoctingentillion":  arrOrders(870) = "octosexagintaoctingentillion":
arrOrders(871) = "novensexagintaoctingentillion":   arrOrders(872) = "septuagintaoctingentillion":  arrOrders(873) = "unseptuagintaoctingentillion":    arrOrders(874) = "duoseptuagintaoctingentillion":   arrOrders(875) = "treseptuagintaoctingentillion":   arrOrders(876) = "quattuorseptuagintaoctingentillion":  arrOrders(877) = "quinseptuagintaoctingentillion":  arrOrders(878) = "seseptuagintaoctingentillion":    arrOrders(879) = "septenseptuagintaoctingentillion":    arrOrders(880) = "octoseptuagintaoctingentillion":  arrOrders(881) = "novenseptuagintaoctingentillion": arrOrders(882) = "octogintaoctingentillion":    arrOrders(883) = "unoctogintaoctingentillion":  arrOrders(884) = "duooctogintaoctingentillion": arrOrders(885) = "tresoctogintaoctingentillion":
arrOrders(886) = "quattuoroctogintaoctingentillion":    arrOrders(887) = "quinoctogintaoctingentillion":    arrOrders(888) = "sexoctogintaoctingentillion": arrOrders(889) = "septemoctogintaoctingentillion":  arrOrders(890) = "octooctogintaoctingentillion":    arrOrders(891) = "novemoctogintaoctingentillion":   arrOrders(892) = "nonagintaoctingentillion":    arrOrders(893) = "unnonagintaoctingentillion":  arrOrders(894) = "duononagintaoctingentillion": arrOrders(895) = "trenonagintaoctingentillion": arrOrders(896) = "quattuornonagintaoctingentillion":    arrOrders(897) = "quinnonagintaoctingentillion":    arrOrders(898) = "senonagintaoctingentillion":  arrOrders(899) = "septenonagintaoctingentillion":   arrOrders(900) = "octononagintaoctingentillion":
arrOrders(901) = "novenonagintaoctingentillion":    arrOrders(902) = "nongentillion":   arrOrders(903) = "unnongentillion": arrOrders(904) = "duonongentillion":    arrOrders(905) = "trenongentillion":    arrOrders(906) = "quattuornongentillion":   arrOrders(907) = "quinnongentillion":   arrOrders(908) = "senongentillion": arrOrders(909) = "septenongentillion":  arrOrders(910) = "octonongentillion":   arrOrders(911) = "novenongentillion":   arrOrders(912) = "decinongentillion":   arrOrders(913) = "undecinongentillion": arrOrders(914) = "duodecinongentillion":    arrOrders(915) = "tredecinongentillion":
arrOrders(916) = "quattuordecinongentillion":   arrOrders(917) = "quindecinongentillion":   arrOrders(918) = "sedecinongentillion": arrOrders(919) = "septendecinongentillion": arrOrders(920) = "octodecinongentillion":   arrOrders(921) = "novendecinongentillion":  arrOrders(922) = "vigintinongentillion":    arrOrders(923) = "unvigintinongentillion":  arrOrders(924) = "duovigintinongentillion": arrOrders(925) = "tresvigintinongentillion":    arrOrders(926) = "quattuorvigintinongentillion":    arrOrders(927) = "quinvigintinongentillion":    arrOrders(928) = "sesvigintinongentillion": arrOrders(929) = "septemvigintinongentillion":  arrOrders(930) = "octovigintinongentillion":
arrOrders(931) = "novemvigintinongentillion":   arrOrders(932) = "trigintanongentillion":   arrOrders(933) = "untrigintanongentillion": arrOrders(934) = "duotrigintanongentillion":    arrOrders(935) = "trestrigintanongentillion":   arrOrders(936) = "quattuortrigintanongentillion":   arrOrders(937) = "quintrigintanongentillion":   arrOrders(938) = "sestrigintanongentillion":    arrOrders(939) = "septentrigintanongentillion": arrOrders(940) = "octotrigintanongentillion":   arrOrders(941) = "noventrigintanongentillion":  arrOrders(942) = "quadragintanongentillion":    arrOrders(943) = "unquadragintanongentillion":  arrOrders(944) = "duoquadragintanongentillion": arrOrders(945) = "tresquadragintanongentillion":
arrOrders(946) = "quattuorquadragintanongentillion":    arrOrders(947) = "quinquadragintanongentillion":    arrOrders(948) = "sesquadragintanongentillion": arrOrders(949) = "septenquadragintanongentillion":  arrOrders(950) = "octoquadragintanongentillion":    arrOrders(951) = "novenquadragintanongentillion":   arrOrders(952) = "quinquagintanongentillion":   arrOrders(953) = "unquinquagintanongentillion": arrOrders(954) = "duoquinquagintanongentillion":    arrOrders(955) = "tresquinquagintanongentillion":   arrOrders(956) = "quattuorquinquagintanongentillion":   arrOrders(957) = "quinquinquagintanongentillion":   arrOrders(958) = "sesquinquagintanongentillion":    arrOrders(959) = "septenquinquagintanongentillion": arrOrders(960) = "octoquinquagintanongentillion":
arrOrders(961) = "novenquinquagintanongentillion":  arrOrders(962) = "sexagintanongentillion":  arrOrders(963) = "unsexagintanongentillion":    arrOrders(964) = "duosexagintanongentillion":   arrOrders(965) = "tresexagintanongentillion":   arrOrders(966) = "quattuorsexagintanongentillion":  arrOrders(967) = "quinsexagintanongentillion":  arrOrders(968) = "sesexagintanongentillion":    arrOrders(969) = "septensexagintanongentillion":    arrOrders(970) = "octosexagintanongentillion":  arrOrders(971) = "novensexagintanongentillion": arrOrders(972) = "septuagintanongentillion":    arrOrders(973) = "unseptuagintanongentillion":  arrOrders(974) = "duoseptuagintanongentillion": arrOrders(975) = "treseptuagintanongentillion":
arrOrders(976) = "quattuorseptuagintanongentillion":    arrOrders(977) = "quinseptuagintanongentillion":    arrOrders(978) = "seseptuagintanongentillion":  arrOrders(979) = "septenseptuagintanongentillion":  arrOrders(980) = "octoseptuagintanongentillion":    arrOrders(981) = "novenseptuagintanongentillion":   arrOrders(982) = "octogintanongentillion":  arrOrders(983) = "unoctogintanongentillion":    arrOrders(984) = "duooctogintanongentillion":   arrOrders(985) = "tresoctogintanongentillion":  arrOrders(986) = "quattuoroctogintanongentillion":  arrOrders(987) = "quinoctogintanongentillion":  arrOrders(988) = "sexoctogintanongentillion":   arrOrders(989) = "septemoctogintanongentillion":    arrOrders(990) = "octooctogintanongentillion":
arrOrders(991) = "novemoctogintanongentillion": arrOrders(992) = "nonagintanongentillion":  arrOrders(993) = "unnonagintanongentillion":    arrOrders(994) = "duononagintanongentillion":   arrOrders(995) = "trenonagintanongentillion":   arrOrders(996) = "quattuornonagintanongentillion":  arrOrders(997) = "quinnonagintanongentillion":  arrOrders(998) = "senonagintanongentillion":    arrOrders(999) = "septenonagintanongentillion": arrOrders(1000) = "octononagintanongentillion": arrOrders(1001) = "novenonagintanongentillion": arrOrders(1002) = "millinillion":   arrOrders(1003) = "millimillion":   arrOrders(1004) = "millibillion":   arrOrders(1005) = "millitrillion":
```

Comment: Part 2 & 3 seems to contain non-english versions of texts...

Comment: @Hannu All names taken from [here](http://www.olsenhome.com/bignumbers/). They are... not common. At some point, the names are created formulaically by combining prefixes instead of being individually defined.

Comment: Ahh... my mistake, the names are 'odd' because they are unusually large.